# При вставке с AUTOINCREMENT ошибка: sqlite3.0perationalError: table ranobes has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite

Создал БД через SQLiteStudio (3.2.1).

```
CREATE TABLE ranobes (
    ranobe_id INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name      STRING (256) 
);
```

Решил добавить запись. Вычитал, что если у поля стоит `AUTOINCREMENT`, то самому `id` писать не надо, само по себе добавится. Просто не нужно в `VALUES` прописывать `ranobe_id`.

```
def add_new_ranobe(self, name):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ranobes VALUES (?)", (name,))
```

Ну и вызвал это дело:

```
db.add_new_ranobe('Книжка1')
```

Но получил такую ошибку:

```
    return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ranobes VALUES (?)", (name,))   
sqlite3.0perationalError: table ranobes has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied
```

Тогда добавил в `VALUES` новое значение, `id`, и в ручную его прописал, теперь запись добавилась, но без учета `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае в SQL команде:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col_name_1, col_name_2, col_name_5)
VALUES (value_for_col_1, value_for_col_2, value_for_col_5)
```

можно указать в какие *столбцы* мы хотим записать данные (*обратите внимание на список столбцов в скобках после имени таблицы*). Если не указать список столбцов после имени таблицы, то подразумевается что мы вставляем данные **во все столбцы таблицы**. Соответственно передав всего одно значение - у нас получается несоответствие - 2 столбца в таблице и всего одно значение передано в `VALUES(...)`.

В вашем случае можно явно указать список столбцов:

```
INSERT INTO ranobes(name) VALUES (?)
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, можете еще один момент подсказать? Я удалил все записи из таблицы, после чего, в пустую таблицу добавил запись, ее номер id оказался на 1 больше того, что я удалял, но я ведь эти записи уже удалил. Как вернуться к индексированию с 1?

Comment: @Cowboyserg, [задайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) этот интересный вопрос отдельно)

Comment: @Cowboyserg делайте DROP TABLE table_name; и созавайте заново. Автоинкременты так просто обнулять нельзя. Нужно делать truncate table в sqllite пересоздавать таблицу

Comment: @Manul74, есть и другие варианты, но, как очень верно заметил vp_arth лучше задать отдельный вопрос и в этом вопросе можно будет дать полноценные ответы с примерами ;)

Comment: @vp_arth, сделал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191638/sqlite-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-1