# Как сбросить счётчик AUTOINCREMENT в таблице в 1 после удаления всех записей?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Был такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1191626), в результате которого получилось использовать `AUTOINCREMENT`.

После чего, через запрос:

```
DELETE FROM ranobes;
```

Удалил все запииси из таблицы. Далее, добавил новую запись, которая проиндексировалось с 6 (в удаленной таблице было 5 записей), то есть индексация сработала таким образом, как будто я и не удалял те записи.

Вопрос таков, а как начать заново индексирование с 1?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/692856/2110496

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Sqlite есть специальная таблица `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` для этого (с которой нужно быть предельно осторожным).

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = 'ranobes';
```

В вашем случае, когда в таблице нет строк, можно также полностью пересоздать таблицу: `DROP TABLE/CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помогло, но для таких как я, которые в этом не шарят стоит дописать, что сначала нужно удалить таблицу DELETE FROM ranobes;. А потом только писать вашу команду. Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: Не, можно выставить любое значение, если выставить значение меньше уже существующего - вы сломаете генератор. Если бы вы не очистили таблицу `DELETE FROM x`, то и вопрос о генерации с 1 у вас бы не возник.

Comment: @vp_arth, оказывается [SQLite достаточно умный - он просто исправит счетчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1191658/211923) как если бы вы ничего не меняли ;)

Answer (score 5):

Дополнение к [ответу уважаемого @vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1191641/211923):

После небольших эксперементов с `SQLite version 3.25.2 2018-09-25` пришел к выводу, что SQLite делает проверку при обнулении счетчика в `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` и если на момент вставки в **непустую** таблицу значение ее счетчика меньше последнего значения из таблицы, то SQLite сам исправит значение счетчика на `last_seq_number`.

Пример:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ranobes;
ranobe_id   name
----------  ----------
1           name1
2           name2
3           name3
4           name4
sqlite> SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE;
name        seq
----------  ----------
ranobes     4
```

т.е. изначально в таблице 4 записи и значение счетчика во внутренней таблице `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` - 4.

Теперь сбросим значение счетчика в ноль:

```
sqlite> UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = 'ranobes';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE;
name        seq
----------  ----------
ranobes     0
```

и попробуем вставить новую запись не опустошив таблицу:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO ranobes (name) VALUES("name5");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE;
name        seq
----------  ----------
ranobes     5
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ranobes;
ranobe_id   name
----------  ----------
1           name1
2           name2
3           name3
4           name4
5           name5
```

SQLite сам исправил значение счетчика!

Т.е. для того чтобы сбросить значение счетчика нужно также опустошить таблицу:

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM ranobes;
sqlite> UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = 'ranobes';
sqlite> INSERT INTO ranobes (name) VALUES("name1");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE;
name        seq
----------  ----------
ranobes     1
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ranobes;
ranobe_id   name
----------  ----------
1           name1
```